# Discrete math logic / proof question

Tags: logic

Is this statement logically equivalent: ∃(() → ()) and ∀() → ∃()? Why? (I'm not sure how to proceed with this. I have to use the "universe of discourse" and not formal proof.)

Comment: Why do you have changed the question ?

Comment: I've rolled it back, If you need it, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\exists x (P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ is equivalent to $\exists x (\neg P(x) \lor Q(x)),$ which is equivalent to $\exists x \neg P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x).$ This is equivalent to $\neg (\forall x P(x) \land \neg (\exists x Q(x)).$ From the definition of implication we then have the statement equivalent to $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \exists x Q(x).$

I am not sure what it means to use a universe of discourse to provide a proof of logical equivalency. Perhaps this means to select a certain universe of discourse (which is simply a nonempty collection of objects) and then describe how each of the above statements are equivalent through informal appeal to examples from the universe of discourse.